# cron + php + linux +symphony не срабатывает команда из крона которая должна дергать симфони

Tags: php, linux, symfony, cron, crontab

Коллеги доброе время суток.
Подскажите.
Есть команда php
'php /home/dev/Desktop/TestDontTach/SymphonyII/isconnect/isconnect/bin/console datatransfer:api:fileControll'
фаил с проэктом находиться по пути
Desktop/TestDontTach/SymphonyII/isconnect/isconnect
Все папки в проэкте имеют права 777 (Так как крон жаловался на права, и продолжает жаловаться судя по лог файлу)
У симфони есть контролер (Консольный) который нужно запускать раз в минуту
Вот его код

```
namespace App\Command;

use App\Command\SupportsDataTranferComand\logger\BusinessErrorLogger;
use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\Storage;
use App\Entity\ProductVariant;
use App\Entity\ProductVariantStorage;
use MyBuilder\Bundle\CronosBundle\Annotation\Cron;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use GuzzleHttp;
use App\Model\DataTransfer;
/// Logger
use App\Command\SupportsDataTranferComand\logger\FileLogger;
use App\Command\SupportsDataTranferComand\logger\BDLogger;
////
use App\Model\UpdateFileController;
use MyBuilder\Bundle\CronosBundle\Annotation;
/**
 * @Cron(minute="/1", noLogs=true)
 */
class DataTransferCommandFileAlarm extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'datatransfer:api:fileControll';

    private $em;
    private $productRep;
    private $productVarRep;
    public $time;
    private $timeStart;
    private $timeFinish;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->em = $em;

        $this->productRep = $em->getRepository(Product::class);
        $this->productVarRep = $em->getRepository(ProductVariant::class);
        $this->time = ["hour"=>(int)date("h"),"timeMeridiem"=>(string)date("A")];
    }

    protected function configure(): void
    {

    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {

        ProgressBar::setFormatDefinition('minimal', 'Progress: %percent%%');

        //$progressBar = new ProgressBar($output);
        //$progressBar->setFormat('%bar%');
        $updateController = new UpdateFileController();
        if($this->time["timeMeridiem"] == "PM"){
            if($this->time["hour"]<11){
                $updateController->setFileControlle("test.txt");
                if($updateController->getStatusFile() != false){
                    $updateController->alarm();
                    dump("Alarm succes !PM");
                }


            }
            else{
                $updateController->setFileControlle("test.txt");
            }
        }

        if($this->time["timeMeridiem"] === "AM"){
            if($this->time["hour"]>8){
                $updateController->setFileControlle("test.txt");
                $updateController->alarm();
                dump("Alarm succes !AM");
            }
            else{
                $updateController->setFileControlle("test.txt");
            }
        }

         return Command::SUCCESS;

    }

}
```

его идея в следующем отслеживать изменения файла каждою минуту, если изменён это хорошо, если долго не приходил фаил, или он долго не менялся то надо бить тревогу.
Соответсвенно я евляюсь рутом на данной системе и могу дергать команду где и как мне угодно. Сама команда сообщает мне фаил свежий или тухлый.
Но когда его дергает крон он говорит что у меня нет на это прав.
Настройка крона

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/dev/sbin:/dev/bin
HOME=/
*/1  *  *   *   *   root  php /home/dev/Desktop/TestDontTach/SymphonyII/isconnect/isconnect/bin/console datatransfer:api:fileControll
```

Так вот а лог выполнения команды следующий

```
[critical] Error thrown while running command "datatransfer:api:fileControll". Message: "Warning: fopen(brain.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied"


In UpdateFileController.php line 82:
                                                                        
  Warning: fopen(brain.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied  
                                                                        

datatransfer:api:fileControll
```

Подскажите как решить эту мелкую но всё же проблему

Comment: прошу прощения открытие файла забыл уточнить public function createJsonFile(){
       $handel = fopen("brain.json","x+");
        fclose($handel);
        file_put_contents('brain.json','
        {
         "hashFile": "'.$this->hashFile.'",
         "lastDateUpdate": "'.time().'"
        }
        '); (Прошу прощения за грязный код, тут его почему-то не отфарматируешь)

Comment: файлы в docroot должны принадлежать одному пользователю. тому самому, от имени которого работает процесс, выполняющий у вас роль http-сервера. от имени этого же пользователя надо создавать и cron-задачи.

Comment: Очень рекомендую указывать абсолютный путь до файла `brain.json`. Неизвестно что cron будет считать текущей директорией. И куда в итоге сохранится файл.